# Access my IIS externally without port forwarding (port 80)

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, iis

Is there a way to Access my IIS which used `Port 80` without port forwarding?

i have the following information:

- my public IP
- the private IP of my PC

maybe there is something like `0.0.0.0\192.168.1.1:80`

Comment: Short answer: no. Longer answer: You could stick your server in a DMZ but port forwarding is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way, without using port-forwarding (or something functionally equivalent under a different name) *if* you are, as you almost certainly are, using a router that is performing network address translation (NAT).

If you have control of an external endpoint you can probably establish a connection to it from the IIS server using tools like netcat or socat. You could then use this established tunnel to communicate with your IIS server.

If you can set up a VPN - this would also allow access.

Answer (score 0):

If you have IPv6, there is no need to port forward (but you will need to make sure the edge firewall/router isn't explicitly blocking incoming packets). In most software, you can listen on `::0` to mean "all IPv6 interfaces" - otherwise you can hardcode your public-facing IPv6 address.